# Access a parent field from sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to access a field being called from the parent query within a nested one and here is my table

TABLE: reminders.

Columns: id:PK, rid:VARCHAR, title:VARCHAR, remind:Integer, start_day:DATE

```
SELECT id, remind, rid, title
FROM reminders
WHERE DATEDIFF(start_day, NOW()) <= (SELECT LEAST(3, remind))
```

Basically the second "remind" column in the LEAST() command is suppossed to reference the first "remind" column value for every row being spanned but for reasons that I can't just imagine i keep getting unexpected returns.

**EDIT**

In response to Sir Gordons that i provide more detailed info, I will try my best but I really do not know how to present table data here, but i'll try.

So basically i'm trying to SELECT all items from the reminders table WHERE the DIFFERENCE between the SET DAY (start_day) and TODAY doesn't exceed one of TWO values, those are either 3 or the value set in the remind column of the current row. Basically if the value set there is less than 3 then it should be used instead, but if it exceeds 3, 3 should be chosen. Here's a visual of the table.

```
+---+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|id | rid             | title              |   start_day     |  remind     |
+---|-----------------|--------------------|-----------------|-------------|
|1  | ER456GH         | This is real deep  | 2014-01-01      |  10         |
|2  | OUBYV90         | This is also deep  | 2014-01-13      |  10         |
|3  | UI90POL         | This is deeper     | 2014-01-13      |  60         |
|4  | TWEET90         | This is just deep  | 2014-01-14      |  0          |
+---+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

So in editing this I realized that there was a false table entry under remind on the 4th entry that was causing it to pull false (i.e where remind = 0). Sigh. Some serious short sight on my part/lack of sleep I guess. The query does work . Thanks again.

Comment: By the way I think naming that `parent-field` is not good, it seems like `OO` inheritance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of data and your desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery here.  Does this work?

```
SELECT id, remind, rid, title
FROM reminders
WHERE DATEDIFF(start_day, NOW()) <= LEAST(3, remind);
```

Comment: But you were right about it probably not needing nesting, this gave the same result as the one I wrote...

Comment: Thanks...it actually does the job it was intended to. The table contained some false data. Thanks again